# Opening a File saved in Blob Variable - APEX 21.2

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm using ORA_EXCEL PL/SQL API to create custom Excel files. I have it set so that when clicking a button it calls a `GENERATE_EXCEL_PROCESS` via a page submit (tried both `Processing` and `After Submit` processing points) and builds the file and saves it to a Blob variable (confirmed file creation is working in separate test writing file to an Oracle Directory).

My goal is to generate the Excel file in PLSQL, save to a blob and then display a download dialog for users to save the excel file locally similarly to the native `Download` link that Classic reports allow you to turn on declaratively.

When run I get a weird APEX error, that I only found by turning Full Trace mode on in debugging. I've included the code below, but I do not know what it means to troubleshoot further. It looks like I get a response back of Blob looking at network tab in devtools.

[image: APEX ERROR]
[image: APEX PROCESS RESPONSE]

```sql
  PROCEDURE apex_file_download(
    p_file_name       VARCHAR2,
    p_generated_file  BLOB,
    p_file_type       VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'EXCEL'
  ) IS

    vcMimeType  VARCHAR2(1000);

    blob_file BLOB;
    blob_size INTEGER;

  BEGIN

      CASE p_file_type
        WHEN 'EXCEL' THEN
          vcMimeType := 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
      END CASE;

      blob_file := p_generated_file;

      -- Get BLOB size
      blob_size := dbms_lob.getlength(blob_file);

      -- Print content type header for MS Excel
      owa_util.mime_header(vcMimeType, FALSE, NULL);

      -- Put BLOB size header
      htp.p('Content-length: '|| blob_size);

      -- Set file name that will be suggested when download dialog appears
      htp.p('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'||p_file_name||'"');

      -- Close header
      owa_util.http_header_close;

      -- Download BLOB
      wpg_docload.download_file(blob_file);

      apex_application.stop_apex_engine;

  EXCEPTION
      WHEN apex_application.e_stop_apex_engine THEN
        NULL;

      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE;
  END;
END;
```

Comment: did you test your approach for downloading another file, a simple txt perhaps?

Comment: Hey Oguen, thanks for the reply. I tested the generation of the file is done correctly writing it to Oracle directory, but did not try as you suggest. Can try that, but wondering if issue is due to me trying to display http headers on a page that has already been rendered. Still learning how the APEX engine works. Wondering if I need to redirect to a new page and run the code above Before Headers or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone provided a solution for me in the Oracle forum. I'm not sure why this works and wish I had a better understanding of the error and how this fixes it, but posting here in case others have the same problem.

[Oracle Forums Solution](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/comment/16821858#Comment_16821858)